# is it grammatical to say "The dog next door barks all the night. I hate it."

Tags: grammar

My friend asked me a question and I couldn't answer.

His question was as follows:

is it grammatical to say **"The dog next door barks all the night. I hate it."**?

Notice that "next door" is an adverb. it must describe a verb and there is no verb before "next door" in the sentence.

Comment: It's not meaningful to ask if a sentence is *true* in this context. What you mean to ask is if it's *grammatical*. (If you really intend to ask if it's *true*, that could only be evaluated by having a recording of the sounds from that night and *proving* if the dog barked or not.)

Comment: yes, I should change my question. it must be " is it grammatical" and not "is it true" .would someone please edit ( I mean change ) my question?  I  can not do that.

Comment: I have done so. But you should be able to do so too—just click the [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/229615/edit) link directly below the question itself (next to share, close, and flag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Next door** in this sentence is not an adverb; it is a modifier (functioning much like an *adjective*) on **dog**.  (If one were to expand the phrase: **the dog [which is] next door**...)

The only problem with the sentence is the last part; the correct phrasing is **all night**, not **all *the* night**.

Answer (score 1):

If you say that the dog next door barks all night, it means that the dog is in the habit of barking all night. It happens often and you hate that.

If it is just tonight the barking has been happening say: "the dog has been barking all night".